# Django/Python - How do I get a count of records in a model where an @property function is True?

Tags: python, django, count, properties

I'm very new to python and django and I'm working on a version of the locallibrary project to learn some concepts.  I've created a model with an @property to show when an item is overdue:

```
@property
def overdue(self):
    is_overdue = False
    if (datetime.date.today() > self.due_date) and self.status != 'c':
            is_overdue = True
    return is_overdue
```

I would like to get a count of all items where overdue=True.  In templates I can use 'overdue' as if it were a field, however, trying to use is in a view like this...

```
num_actions_overdue = Action.objects.filter(overdue='True').count()
```

...throws an error:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'overdue' into field.
```

Is there a simple way to count all overdue records?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: FYI that method is just `return (datetime.date.today() > self.due_date) and self.status != 'c'`

Comment: As the duplicate says, you can't. You have to filter on Python's level. for example, `len(list(filter(lambda action: action.is_overdue, Action.objects.all())))`

Comment: Thanks for the response folks.  Guess I need to learn more about the concepts before asking questions, as I didn't spot any of those as duplicating my question beforehand :/